# modifying a record in the middle of an approval process

Tags: force.com, approval-process

I need to modify a field for a record that is being approved. I unlocked the record, and made the change... now I need to re-lock the record.

How do I re-lock it? I don't see a button on the top of the page... what happened, and what's the fix?

Comment: Is there a flag you can set via DML operations?

Comment: i did it manually, and this is in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can determine from the documentation (or lack thereof), you can't re-lock a record without rejecting or approving the current step. Administrators do not need to unlock a record in order to edit the record, and therefore shouldn't be unlocking records. You'll have to reject the entire process and start over with that record.

Comment: yea, thats what i'm finding too... I listened to the user when he told me to unlock the record, when i could have edited it.... Totally ughing right now on that....